# Strong convexity of a function with cases

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Given a set $S = \{x_1,\dotsc,x_n\} \subset \mathbb{R}$, is the function

\begin{align}
f&: (0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R} \\
f&(p) = 2p^2 + \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \max(0, -p^2-x_i)
\end{align}

strongly convex? (What if $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$?)

I know $p^2$ is strongly convex. Let $P = \{x_i \in S : x_i + p^2 \geq 0\}$ and $N = S\setminus P$ then

\begin{align}
f(p) =
\begin{cases}
2p^2 & \text{ for all } x_i \in P \\
2p^2 - \frac{1}{|N|}\sum_{i=1}^{|N|} -p^2  -\frac{1}{|N|}\sum_{i=1}^{|N|}x_i & \text{ for all } x_i \in N
\end{cases}
\end{align}
so in both cases $f$ is strongly convex. Is this argumentation valid?

Comment: Could you please specify the sign of the $x_i$'s and $p$? Is $p$ a continuous variable?

Comment: The $x_i$ are $p$ real numbers and $p>0$ if necessary. Why could the sign of $x_i$ play a role? They are constants.

Answer (score 1):

First we can assume $x_i<0,\forall i$. We can write

$f(p) = \frac{1}{N} \sum_i^N ( p^2+\max\{0, -p^2-x_i\} )= \frac{1}{2}\sum_i^n \phi(p)_i,$

Then it is easy to see that $\phi(p)_i = -x_i$ for $p\in [-\sqrt x_i,\sqrt x_i]$, while $\phi(p)_i= p^2 $ otherwise. This is strictly convex. Each $\phi(p)_i$ is known as Huber penalty function (see http://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/ pag 299).

The $f(p)$ function is then the sum of strictly convex functions, and therefore strictly convex.

Comment: I think in a special case I a can add a convex and a concave function and get a convex function. For example $p^2-p^2$ is constant $0$ and convex.

Comment: Even more $2p^2-p^2$ is the sum of a strongly convex and strongly concave function that is strongly convex.

Comment: You are right. I update the post.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Please, note that I am talking about *strong* not strict convexity. As in my original question your argumentation has to consider two cases.